# AWS Loadbalancer stuck on External-IP Pending State

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-eks, amazon-elb, terraform-cdk

After creating EKS cluster loadbalancer is stuck in pending state. All of my subnet is public and I add shared and eld(elb?) tag also. This issue comes when I create nodegroup using launch template using Terraform CDK.

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   172.20.220.13   <pending>     80:31789/TCP,443:32706/TCP   60m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      172.20.84.242   <none>        443/TCP
```

Comment: Please check the answer of the same question: [loadbalancer-external-ip-stuck-in-pending](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854796/loadbalancer-external-ip-stuck-in-pending/73635036#73635036)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please, check logs of the serivce `kubectl describe svc ingress-nginx-controller -n your_namespace` and share a deployment. I assume, that you reached the quota of Load Balancers, and Elastic IPs in your region

> Network Load Balancers per Region 50, Classic Load Balancers per Region 20, Application Load Balancers per Region 50

> By default, all AWS accounts are limited to five (5) Elastic IP addresses per Region
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/elastic-ip-addresses-eip.html#using-instance-addressing-limit

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this on EKS using terraform. In my case, turns out we hit our account's quota limit on classic load balancers (20/20). File an increase limit request and you're good to go.

> Network Load Balancers per Region 50, Classic Load Balancers per Region 20, Application Load Balancers per Region 50